# Unable to send to Kafka topic (Confluent Cloud) from Azure Function

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, azure-functions, confluent-platform

My issue:

The code doesn't get past the ProduceAsync() call, and doesn't throw any exceptions. No message appears on the topic in Kafka. The function does not fail, it simply never completes, meaning it never even logs status to wherever the Azure portal fetches the data it displays under "Monitoring" from. It doesn't trigger any exception for exceeding the max amount of time a function can run. However, the function is executed, as ApplicationInsights shows my debug log statements in its trace messages.

I've tried several different approaches, but here's the code for the latest one (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task RunAsync(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context,
    [HttpClientFactory]HttpClient httpClient
)
{
    try {
        // ...
        using (var kafkaProducer = initKafkaProducer(config))
        {
            var myHelper = new MyHelper(/*...*/, kafkaProducer);
            foreach (var obj in objects)
            {
                await myHelper.ProcessObject(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        //...
        throw new Exception("My error message", ex);
    }
}

private static IProducer<Null, string> initKafkaProducer(IConfigurationRoot config)
{
    var pConfig = new ProducerConfig
    {
        BootstrapServers = config["BootstrapServers"],
        SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
        SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
        SaslUsername = config["Username"],
        SaslPassword = config["Password"],
        MessageSendMaxRetries = 10,
        RetryBackoffMs = 250,
        Acks = Acks.All,
        LingerMs = 5
    };

    return new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(pConfig).Build();
}


public class MyHelper
{
    public async Task ProcessObject(MyObject obj)
    {
        try
        {
            //...
            await sendToKafkaTopic(obj);
            _log.LogInformation($"DEBUG: Successfully sent to Kafka");
            //...
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("My error message...", ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task sendToKafkaTopic(MyObject obj)
    {
        string topic = _config["KafkaTopic"];
        var message = new Message<Null, string> { Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) };

        try
        {
            var deliveryResult = await _kafkaProducer.ProduceAsync(topic, message);
            _log.LogInformation($"DEBUG: Delivered the following to {deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}:\n\n{deliveryResult.Value}");
        }
        catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
        {
            var error = e.Error;

            if (error.IsError && error.IsFatal)
            {
                string errorMessage = "FATAL Kafka error! ";
                if (error.IsBrokerError)
                {
                    errorMessage += "BrokerError. ";
                }
                else if (error.IsLocalError)
                {
                    errorMessage += "LocalError. ";
                }

                errorMessage += $"Error code: {error.Code}. Reason: {error.Reason}";
                throw new Exception(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach I've tried is using the Produce() call, sending with it a handler for the DeliveryReport, and using the `_kafkaProducer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` call. That made it look like everything went well, but the messages didn't show up in Kafka.

I've also tried using the `ProduceAsync(topic, message).ContinueWith((t) => if(t.IsFaulted)...)` approach, and that seems to work for a little while, but after a random amount of function invocations it stops working and I have to redeploy the app to get it working again (might be a coincidence that restarting it didn't work but redeploying did - but it's been the case several times).

This is a V2 function app targeting .NET Core 2.1. I'm using the Confluent.Kafka version 1.4.0 NuGet package. It's running on the consumption plan, and I'm publishing from Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Which library you are using?

Comment: There's nothing else that has any relevance to the sending of messages to Kafka (it's just getting and processing the data that is to be sent to Kafka - and sending to Kafka is the last step). And as I mentioned at the bottom there, I'm using "Confluent.Kafka 1.4.0".

Comment: They just released version 1.4.2 of the Confluent.Kafka client, and upgrading to that seems to have fixed it. Will keep an eye on it to see if it suddenly stops working again, but it seems logical that it was a client issue.

Comment: So, yes, 1.4.2 fixed the issue initially, but then when I moved to PROD the topic was corrupt so it just hung when trying to send to it (no exception or anything, just timed out eventually). Recreated the topic and then it worked. But now, after running fine for a few days it's just timing out 100% of the time again. Restarting the app doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things, it seems, that can cause these symptoms. As I mention in my comment to the OP, upgrading Confluent.Kafka from 1.4.0 to 1.4.2 solved my initial issue. However, after a few days the exact same symptoms appeared, and sending to a different topic didn't help.

To find out what was going on, I enabled all debugging output from the client by setting the client config property `Debug = "all"`. That resulted in the following output from an instance of the function app that worked:

```
Level: Debug
Instance Name: rdkafka#producer-1
Facility: CERTROOT
Message: [thrd:app]: 38/38 certificate(s) successfully added from Windows Certificate Root store
```

And the following from an instance of the function app that didn't work:

```
Level: Debug
Instance Name: rdkafka#producer-25
Facility: CERTROOT
Message: [thrd:app]: Failed to open Windows certificate Root store: Access is denied...: falling back to OpenSSL default CA paths

Level: Debug
Instance Name: rdkafka#producer-25
Facility: BROKERFAIL
Message: [thrd:sasl_ssl://redacted/boot]: sasl_ssl://redacted/bootstrap: failed: err: Local: SSL error: (errno: No such file or directory)
```

Found a work-around from [the client issue tracker](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1112#issuecomment-558906211), but it didn't work initially. Had to specify the full path to the cacert.pem file (`D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\cacert.pem`) as well as make sure to NOT deploy the app as a package. It seems that last part was the main culprit this time, and something the Azure team is looking into. Hopefully, they'll resolve this so that we don't have to use and manage our own CA certificate file.

Apparently, it's quite common to have to specify the path to root CAs when using serverless architectures, but in the case of Azure Functions it *shouldn't* be necessary (but might be for some people).